# CSS: set div heigth to 100%

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Please take a look at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/TpWNY/#base

I would like `<div class="client">` to "inherit" `<div class="contact">`'s height (Both inner div's to have the same size)

Keep in mind that the content on both `<div class="client">` or `<div class="contact">` will dynamically change. So, there's no way to know a predefined height. HOWEVER, `<div class="client">` will always have 2 or 3 lines.

**HTML**

```
<div id="conteiner">
    <div class="client">Name: <br/>Phone:<br/>Emergency</div>
    <div class="contact">
        Contact 1<br/>
        Contact 2<br/>
        Contact 3<br/>
        Contact 4<br/>
        Contact 5<br/>
        Contact 6<br/>
        Contact 7<br/>
        Contact 8<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#conteiner {position: relative;}
#conteiner div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid red;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
}
#conteiner .client {
    width: 200px;
}
#conteiner .contact {
    width: 400px;
}
```

**=== EDIT (07/12/2012) ===**

Final jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/TpWNY/

Thank you @[christofer-vilander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1137696/christofer-vilander) !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` and make them behave like table elements?

Something like this - [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4WSt3/4/)

Comment: This answer is perfect. Not only that, I can apply it for different situation (other than this one) like for vertical columns and such.

Comment: Thanks for changing the container into a class. I did not see that error.

Answer (score 4):

Just this once, I'd recommend using `<table>` as you are in fact making a table. :)

Comment: Yep, tables can actually be good although they have a bad reputation. Tables are especially good for...tables.

Comment: @daniel The problem with this, the data is coming from a database query and I do not have a way to tell how many rows to span (`<div class="contact">`)

Comment: @daniel how are you going to specify `rowspan="x"` if you do not know X?

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, then you want client div and contact div height should be same one.

Please use below code for the same :-

```
​$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.client').height($('.contact').height());
});​
```

Please check and let me know in case of any help or concern.

Regards,
Durgaprasad

Comment: Can this also be accomplished with css?

Comment: As far as I know, you can either go with table layout or have to use JavaScript.

Comment: There is an article on how to make two 2 div element height same.
Please refer http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight link

Comment: I tried the documentation you provided and it did not work: http://jsfiddle.net/omarjuvera/TpWNY/3/

Answer (score 1):

`height:100%;` only works when the parent element has a set height. You can do something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/TpWNY/2/

```
#conteiner {
    position: relative;
    height:200px;  // set height of container. 
}
#conteiner div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid red;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:auto; // allow the div to scroll if necessary.
}
#conteiner .client {
    width: 200px;
}
#conteiner .contact {
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: this would work if I know the height I want to set them to. However, the height will change dynamically according to the content. -I updated my question to include this point I forgot to mention.